# Limit of a MultiVariable Equation

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Hey guys I have a problem that asked to:

Evaluate the following limit: 
$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x,y) = \frac{2x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$$ along $y = mx$ and $y = mx^k$

I understand how to calculate the limit at $(0,0)$ (I got $0$) but how does "along $y = mx$ and $y = mx^k$" affect the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of evaluating along "paths" is to show that the limit is dependent on $m$ and therefore not unique. So suppose that the limit does exist then the following must be true
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x, y) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x, mx) = L_1$$ 
$$  \lim_{x \to 0} f(x, y) = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x, mx^k) = L_2 $$
$$ L_1 = L_2$$
If you can show that $L_1 \neq L_2$, then you can show that the limit does not exist. In your particular example try evaluating the limit along $y = mx^2$.

Comment: okay thank you!